# How to identify the roads on the map to route just as Google Maps does?

Tags: android, dictionary, path, routes

do you know how can we create our map and show the ways from a certain locations to destinations ? Without using google map , just using a picture of a map , is there any way to draw routes on it?I am not asking projects or codes , just need some suggestions related to drawings and considering the obstacles in the way ?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your way points in somewhere(maybe in db or in xml file etc) and also for getting map base you should have a map provider like yahoo, bing, google or openstreetmap(which is free to use - no api key needed considering others)

after having these two sources you can use Geoserver(which is opensource map data manipulater and provider) to put these sources together and get them as map base image.

considering your "just using a picture of a map" is an owerwellming issue. Because you will have to do some calculation to find where to put your points programatically. So Geoserver does that automatically.

also I suggest you to hava a look at osmdroid and osmbonuspack they may help.